# How do I import a base.sql file

Tags: mysql

I got a base.sql file from a Google Code repository but I don`t know how to set it up on my MAMP so I can use the database.

How do I import a base.sql file into a self-hosted mysql directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the mysql command:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword -h hostname database < base.sql
```

Comment: +1 I did this several times to test a client I wrote. The SQL file was about 100 MB and it worked perfectly. :)